# errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"

Tags: swift

I am trying to display or upload UIImage and I am getting this error.

> "errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate { 

// linked labels and UiButtons

@IBOutlet weak var ifix: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var UIImage: UIImageView!
let someImageView: UIImageView = {
    let theImageView = UIImageView()
    theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // call this property so the image is added to your view
    return theImageView
}()


@IBAction func UploadImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self;
    myPickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any])
    {
        let image_data = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        let imageData:Data = image_data!.pngData()!
        _ = imageData.base64EncodedString()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


@IBAction func UIShuffle(_ sender: UIButton) {
}


@IBAction func UIReset(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    view.addSubview(someImageView) //This add it the view controller without constraints
    someImageViewConstraints() //This function is outside the viewDidLoad function that controls the constraints

}
//  `.isActive = true` after every constraint
func someImageViewConstraints() {
    someImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
    someImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
    someImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    someImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 28).isActive = true


}

}
```

Comment: did u manage to fix it? I'm struggling with this issue for some time...and not a single answer helped me ...

Comment: No I haven’t ! Am still trying. I will let you know if I fix it

Comment: I've also opened a post a while ago whit no concrete answer. It's getting annoying and frustrating. I don't know what I'm doing wrong because with the camera it's working but with the library NOT..

Comment: Did your app’s Info.plist contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDiscription key with String value explaining ? If not, you have to add a purpose String to info.plist . That’s basically allowing the app to access you pic gallery .

Comment: I have that, also the delegates and protocols

Comment: Humm  Ok so did description  displayed when you try  first time accessing the functionality ? Accept or deny ?

Comment: I also have this message using ionic - cordova - and it is harmless (for now at least)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message is harmless. The message comes from the OS and is related to the OS keeping an eye out for any newly discovered extensions related to whatever your app is doing. I see it often on macOS when displaying an open file dialog. While browsing around for a file, the OS is checking to see if there are any file-related extensions it needs to load in order to show you something. When the user presses "OK" or "Cancel" it stops searching for the extensions and spits that message to the console. I gather iOS may be doing something similar, perhaps related to share or other user-file-related activities. The message does not indicate an error in your application.

Comment: how do i fix it then? I cant seem to display it on the UIImage whenever i upload image

Comment: Fix what? As mentioned, the message is not an error. Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to do and what is going wrong?

Comment: Ok ! On the UploadImage button func . I am trying to load a pic from my gallery file and once i choose pic to load doesn't display or load, on the UIImageView it just empty.

Comment: I  don't see a call to `imageView.needsDisplay = true`. Adding that might get it to update.